# Node Hierachy: Change Parent in Bulk

Tags: nodes

I'm migrating a current site from Wordpress to Drupal 7 and I'm beating my head against a wall with node hierarchy.  I can't believe this is as difficult as it seems!

I have imported the Wordpress content (which was only 'pages') and everything now shows up as 'basic page' in Drupal under Content.  Most of my pages had a parent-child relationship, and while I can go through every node and type in the proper parent for that node, this seems ridiculous as it is 5 or more clicks per node for every one of hundreds of nodes.

Surely there is a way to select a group of nodes and indicate the parent node of all of those in the group, or perhaps even a drag-and-drop interface.

This is basic stuff and there are posts clear back to 2006 complaining about the difficulty of this.  Surely it is not still this much of a pain...  Is it?