# How to create sections simply

Tags: taxonomy-terms, nodes

I am completely new to Drupal albeit I got some strong knowledge of Plone. I understand my difficulties might come from the 2 CMS have somewhat different ways to layout things.

I have read the "Structure guide" on Drupal website and I am quite puzzled about how to organise the site nodes. I intend to create a file-system-like hierarchy of nodes. While creating nodes by themselves is quite easy I can't find how to easily organise them. Am I right to understand I need to add tags to each and every node, then to use taxonomies to make hierarchies of tags?

I read [Node Hierachy: Change Parent in Bulk](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111634/node-hierachy-change-parent-in-bulk) which gave me some hints but unfortunately setting the parent element does not work for articles.

Is it not possible to browse the web site to some node then "Add content" as a child node of the displayed node and have this (and every subsequent) child added to an automatically generated menu? Or maybe I need some module for this?

Thanks in advance, I fear I'm completely lost!

Comment: Have a look at the book module that ships with Drupal. It allows one to have pages with child pages. I guess that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Drupal makes fewer assumptions about your requirements out of the box than other CMSs. As such, there are probably half a dozen ways you could solve this, some with contrib modules, some with just core modules, depending on your exact requirements. If your requirements are very simple, for example, you can just use a menu or the core book module. If your requirements are more advanced you might need to look at the Entity Reference/Relation modules and see what they can provide. Using taxonomy as you've already mentioned is also a common approach

Comment: Don't worry about feeling lost, either, Drupal is a massive ecosystem and it's natural to feel a bit confused about where to start. If I could offer any advice, it would be to install as many test sites as you need and just get stuck in, trying one thing after another, and seeing what sticks for your requirements. When you hit a "can I actually do X with this approach?", a question here usually gets it sorted